# Are there Android virtual devices other than just smart phones?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am using the Android IDE within Eclipse. Are there other Android virtual devices (emulators) other than the options that come with the IDE. Specifically, I want to emulate a scanner device (the kind for keeping track of inventory in a warehouse or a store) - information is below for the device. What are my best options for testing software that would run on this device, given that I don't have the device?

Scanning device: MX9500
Companies website is - [link to company site](http://www.mobilex-tech.com/product/html/?16.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there Android virtual devices other than just smart phones?

There are no "Android virtual devices" for phones or tablets. The "Device Definitions" tab in the AVD Manager happens to use names of some devices, but that is just to provide some basic screen characteristics (resolution, etc.). When you create an AVD from the "Nexus 5" device definition, you are not emulating a Nexus 5 -- you are running an Android emulator with a particular screen, OS version, etc. configuration that happens to correspond with a Nexus 5.

> Are there other Android virtual devices (emulators) other than the options that come with the IDE.

You are welcome to create your own device definitions through the AVD Manager.

> What are my best options for testing software that would run on this device, given that I don't have the device?

You are welcome to create a device definition in the AVD Manager that matches that device's screen size, Android OS version, etc. It will not emulate scanning, so if your app depends upon the device's ability to scan barcodes, you will need to buy the device or otherwise work with the device manufacturer directly.

Comment: Thanks - that was more or less what I needed to know. It would be helpful if anyone else has worked with this device (or a similar one) and recommends anything for it or about it.